# What should I look for when evaluating groupsets?

Tags: groupsets

It's my first time building a bike and I already bought the frame of a SuperSix EVO Hi-MOD (minus the fork), and I'm trying to find a compatible and cost efficient groupset that will work. What do I need to look for to check what will and won't work. And, does anyone have any insight on preferences?

Comment: What will you be using the bicycle for?

Comment: @AndrewMorton with a SuperSix Eco HiMod, road cycling seems like a safe bet.

Comment: @PaulH I just knew "cycling" had to come into it somewhere ;) Yeah, but given that $5000 groupsets would be a fair match for a frame like that and yet the OP wrote "cost-efficient," maybe some narrowing down of parameters would be useful.

Comment: Supersix Evo and cost effective don't really belong together

Comment: it would be helpful to know which generation of this frame you got

Comment: Availability in your area may constrain your options. Specially Campagnolo has been very short in supply since the pandemic.

Comment: to be clear, there are some generations of the super six (most or all of them until the current one) that are stereotypical pro bikes made to accept any road group so as to present the fewest possible obstacles for accepting sponsor components. That all changed with the current one, which is a PF30A frame, and so while you can still run pretty much whatever road crank you want, the conversation about what BB is needed to do it is more complex.

Comment: Did you have an overall budget in mind for this build?  You could end up accdentally spending a lot of money here, presumably there's wheels and all the little things left to buy as well.

Answer (score 4):

The supersix is a performance race bike as you are no doubt aware.

Your main consideration is whether the bike has rim or disc brakes.

Any of the major manufacturer's road groups would be appropriate.  You may wish to choose something from the top three tiers to match the performace of the frame.

Shimano 105, Ultegra or Dura-Ace

Campagnolo Super Record, Record or Chorus

SRAM Rival, Force or Red

Your frame should be suitable for both mechanical and electronic shifting, but you should check before you invest in Di2.

You probably have a hole in the frame for a PF30 bottom bracket or similar. Check the shell width. Campagnolo and SRAM make suitable bottom brackets for their groups but you will need to find a 3rd party manufacturer's bottom bracket to correctly fit the Shimano chanset. There are many options.

If the frame is for disc, make sure you choose the correct mount brake calipers. Flat mount is the de facto standard for road now but post mount existed on earlier models. If the frame is for rim brakes, I belive all SuperSix bikes use a standard recessed-nut caliper, which is the most common option when buying a grouppo.

I don't think there are any other pitfalls as far as you are concerned. Next, the wheels...

Answer (score 1):

I would look at bottom bracket sizing, likely a PF30 but it could be a BB30.  Also you want to check rear axle sizing, is it a QR or a thru axle, disc brake mounts if they have it, and even front derailleur fit just on the safe side.

Unfortunately, when buying a frame, you can't assume anything is standard.